# How to connect Woocommerce WordPress plugin to a Spring Boot API based on Spring Security Oauth2 JWT?

Tags: spring, wordpress, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, server-to-server

I am a Spring Developer trying to figure out how to connect a WordPress WooCommerce Website to my REST Spring boot Service. I haven't worked with WordPress, so there are a lot of unknown unknowns for me there. I am in collaboration with another developer on the WordPress side of things, trying to solve this issue, but we are a little lost.

Are there Best Practices for a WordPress website to access the Spring boot Oauth2 API (including JWT Token delivery Service) ?

### CONCRETE DESCRIPTION OF MY SITUATION:

---

**State right now** (working):

Someone orders a Product on the WooCommerce website and the order status is set to processing.

**The goal**:

WordPress WooCommerce Backend calls the Spring boot API to send how many Products were ordered.

### WHAT WE FOUND OUT AND WHAT WE TRIED:

---

**Spring boot:**

We found out that Spring boot outh2 is the way to go for the REST API ENDPOINT
The only resource I found about this are this once, which are very good and sufficient:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE

**WordPress:**

The Problem is, that we find a lot on WordPress Webhooks but not a lot on how to call an API Endpoint with a Token system.
Here are some resources we worked through, which are not sufficient:

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html?shell#webhooks

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wordpress+oauth2+rest+call&t=bravened&ia=web

### WHAT WE THINK TO KNOW ABOUT THE SERVER TO SERVER COMMUNICATION IN THIS CASE** (Handshake):

---

1. In **WordPress**, I manually safely **store a Username and a Password** which
   Spring Security knows about, on WordPress.
2. WordPress, an **order** has been finished.
3. WordPress calls Spring boot Https Request to **/api** with **Payload**:
   OrderInformation, **Password and Username**.
4. **Spring** sees that there is **no Token** or the Token is outdated
5. **Spring** searches the Request Payload for **Username and Password**
6. **Spring** **generates** a signed **JWT Token** based on Username and Password.
7. **WordPress** receives that Token and **stores** is safely
8. WordPress HTTPS Request **/api** with **Payload**: OrderInformation, **Token**.
9. Spring **validates** the **Token**, accepts the OrderInformation
10. Spring does what ever it needs to do with the information and when
    **everything works out**
11. Spring Oauth2 somehow has to tell Woocomerce that the information
    was **successfully delivered**. **Otherwise** Woocomerce has to **resend** the
    information. And start form point

### WHAT WE HOPE THIS POST SHOULD ACCOMPLISH FOR PEOPLE WITH THE SAME QUESTION:

---

If someone knows any resource or best practices how to configure WordPress WooCommerce, please let us, who have a lot of unknown unknowns, know what to do next.
We hope this post and its answers can be a gateway and vertex for other people to find the information they need.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Hello. This is a well thought out question, but questions asking for opinions are off topic here.  Perhaps there is a better location for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. Since I am new with asking questions online, I read through the resources you provided and couldn't find a suited place to ask these types of questions. They are stated as being off-topic here, but where are they asked? I will repost the question at the desired location. Should this post be removed here? I appreciate the good answer and don't know if it is better to leave this question here. 

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about Spring Boot API specifically, but I have done this type of integration with other REST API's.

I would recommend using [wordpress action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/). The hook that I would recommend you to use is `woocommerce_order_status_changed`.

```
// define the woocommerce_order_status_changed callback 
function action_woocommerce_order_status_changed( $this_get_id, $this_status_transition_from, $this_status_transition_to, $instance ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```

At the place of `// make action magic happen here...` write the logic where you contact with your API. Run your code when `$this_status_transition_to` is processing. The `$instance` should have woocommerce order instance which you can use to push to API.

Some pointers that I would like to give are.

1. Save the API Token/Credentials in an Enviroment Variable for security.
2. Would recommend using [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html) package to make http request. Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install the package.

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable information.
This is exactly what I was asking for.